# How to use two styles tags inline?

Tags: html

How to insert this,

```
style="text-align:justify"
```

to the following code?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table style="border:1px solid yellow;">
      <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid red;">England</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid blue;">France</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By writing it into the desired position?

Comment: For which of them you are going to use text-align?

Comment: Insert this one: <td style="border:1px solid red;">England</td>

Comment: So easy: `<td style="border:1px solid red; text-align:justify">England</td>`

Comment: @dr.Code no problem, but you could search for this instead of posting a question.

Comment: @Dr.Code It's better to learn the basics and then work on something. You can check online tutorials which teach the details and also allow to experiment online.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you can simply put the argument `text-align` inside the `td` without needing to put it in a `.css stylesheet` like follows:

```
<td style="border:1px solid red; text-align: justify">England</td>
```